# Exporting dynamic HTML to excel .NET

Tags: .net, html, export-to-excel

I have an aspx page to display pages of report. The sections of report are each in a separate panel with navigation links. Say, clicking "Next" turns off current panel and turns on the "Next" page's panel.

I need to export this whole report to excel.

How to do it in asp.net ?

Can i get similar navigation and formatting in excel ?

**EDIT** I am using gridviews and .NET charting controls. (No 3rd party package outside .NET)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not mentioning that you are using a commercial Reporting package, I asume your reports are HTML pages. For such a scenario, I don't think that you have a direct path to Excel.

When I have to generate Microsoft Excel files, I usually choose one of these options:

1. Use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) and optionally their [Smart Marker](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/smart-markers.html) feature to generate new Excel files from scratch or from templates *-or-*
2. Use [XtraReports](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/asp-net.xml) from DevExpress to create HTML/ASPX reports that have Excel export built-in.

Maybe this would be an option for you, too. Both packages are commercial, though.

Comment: I found some info on this: ASP.NET has Navigation controls in MVC model.